# How to select and iterate through a XML xElement node from attribute values?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a xml like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Category ID="1" AICategoryName="Schedule K: Income/Loss" Taxonomy="K">
   <Level1 ID="11965" Name="Guaranteed payments" Taxonomy="4">
      <Level2 ID="27058" Name="Gtd Pmts(trade/bus) to Sch. M-1" Taxonomy="1"> 
      </Level2>

      <Level2 ID="27059" Name="Gtd Pmts not to Sch. M-1" Taxonomy="2">      
      </Level2>
   </Level1>

   <Level1 ID="119652" Name="2Guaranteed payments" Taxonomy="4">
      <Level2 ID="227058" Name="2Gtd Pmts(trade/bus) to Sch. M-1" Taxonomy="1"> 
      </Level2>

      <Level2 ID="227059" Name="2Gtd Pmts not to Sch. M-1" Taxonomy="2">      
      </Level2>
   </Level1>
</Category>
```

I want to get the child nodes under a parent node by providing the parent node attribite ID.

for example if I provide Level1 and 11965, I should get all the level 2 nodes and their Name and IDs.

I have tried this code.

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

        var xl = from xml2 in xd.Descendants("Level1")
                 where xml2.Parent.Attribute("ID").Value == parentNode.ID
                 select xml2;
```

But the code yeilds no results. also once I get the xl, how can I iterate through it to get child node names and IDs?

Comment: `xd.Descendants("Level1")` selects elements that _are_ Level1, not the descendants _of_ Level`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var nodes = (from n in xd.Root.Desendants(tagName/*Level1*/) where n.Attribute("Id").Value == "idValue" select n.Elements()).single().select(n=>{return new{
Id = n.attribute("Id").value,
Name = n.attribute("Name").value,
Taxonomy = n.attribute("Taxonomy").value
}});
```

you can also change the code above if the tag name requested is always "Level1" and the xml struvvture is fixed, to this.

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var nodes = (from n in xd.Root.Elements("Level1") where n.Attribute("Id").Value == "idValue" select n.Elements()).single().select(n=>{return new{
    Id = n.attribute("Id").value,
    Name = n.attribute("Name").value,
    Taxonomy = n.attribute("Taxonomy").value
    }});
```

Comment: thankx for the upvote.. this code also solves your problem dosent it?

Answer (score 1):

LINQ (suppose you always get single Level1 node for provided id):

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
int parentId = 119652;
var nodes = (from level1 in xd.Descendants("Level1")
            where ((int)level1.Attribute("ID")) == parentId
            select level1.Descendants("Level2"))
            .Single()
            .Select(level2 => new { ID = (int)level2.Attribute("ID"), 
                                    Name = level2.Attribute("Name").Value });
```

Iterate

```
foreach (var level2 in nodes)
    // level2.Name and level2.ID
```

If there possible that Level1 node not exist for provided id or you have several Level1 nodes with same ID:

```
int parentId = 119652;
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var query = xd.Descendants("Level1")
              .Where(level1 => ((int)level1.Attribute("ID")) == parentId)
              .SelectMany(level1 => level1.Descendants("Level2"))
              .Select(level2 => new { ID = (int)level2.Attribute("ID"), 
                                      Name = level2.Attribute("Name").Value });

foreach (var level2 in query)
    // level2.Name and level2.ID
```